# Looking for an updated Visual Studio 2010 Yaml syntax highlighting

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, yaml

I have to work a lot with the flexible file format Yaml, i like its human readability but still I look for a support in Visual Studio 2010. Before I used this .NET based solution [Yaml on Codeplex](http://yaml.codeplex.com/), it worked fairly ok despite some quirks but it does not seem to be updated any further. I did do a google search but It didnt yield any valuable results. May it be that the format is nice for humans but hard for computers to parse? Hope to receive any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did ask more about [Yaml on Codeplex](http://yaml.codeplex.com/) and the happy news is that there will be some time later support for 2010 too :) , see [Discussion](http://yaml.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=237387) here.